# Correlation test

Tags: correlation, chi-squared-test

Please consider this table:

```
     above  below
A11  35,712 15,864
B    22,723 29,741
B10   3,513  5,427
B3b   5,146  3,780
...
```

I need to test the existence of a correlation between the two the variables. If they would be "counted individuals" (I also apologize for my basic ignorance ...) I'd use a chi-square or a Fisher test.
But here the values are kg obtained as sum of subsequent weighings.
What should I use ?
Many thanks in advance.
UPDATE
I should have been more informative: the table represents the quantity of certain materials above or below a certain geographical altitude, expressed in kilograms. They cannot be counted because they are fragments of different dimensions. Weight is a more meaningful measure of their presence in the two regions (above/below).
The values are not the result of a sampling but the total weight of each material in the area under study.

Comment: You could e.g. plot values above and below on a scatter plot or even a bar chart. You could calculate any standard kind of correlation. Whether any of those is a helpful thing to do depends entirely on what is expected or being checked for. Without that context we are just guessing wildly,

Comment: Thanks for the extra details. I don't see any problem in using weights here. I don't think you have to defend that in any sense. Unfortunately I don't have a sense of what you want to do with the data.  Are you interested in looking for patterns or do you have a hypothesis to test?

Comment: Thank you Nick for your interest. I just need to test the null hypothesis as I would do with the chi-square for counted individuals. In crassest terms: the observed distributions of the different materials above and below the reference quote is compatible with a random distribution or do we have an indication that it has been driven by "something" (just as an example, the time when the deposition occurred) ?

Comment: "a random distribution" here I guess means equal weights above and below in which case I imagine a paired t-test would be a start but perhaps on log weights not weights. Correlation is not the right word here: its statistical sense is broad but not broad enough to cover any kind of search for pattern or relationship. As an occasional geomorphologist I have a limited sense of what may be useful for you and it's more likely to be looking at graphs and detailed  thinking about your sites than reducible to a significance test.

Comment: Single weights, here, are just random pickings in time and space for which we only know wether the sample was taken below or above. With the sample data I showed it's very clear that the distribution in not even similar but there could be cases where it's not so evident. I'm not a statistician (you guessed ?) and perhaps on a totally wrong path, but what I'm looking for is a tool that could turn on a red alert saying "watch out, here there could be something worth investigating further". I assumed that the chi-square could be that tool for counted individuals (as rough as it may be). Tks again

Comment: Chi-square is, as said, and despite a down-voted  answer that the poster won't delete, utterly irrelevant here. But now I don't understand the form of your data. To me your question (including the Update) clearly implies that above and below weights are paired. So, I am at a loss to know what to advise or which of my advice to date still applies. I think I should bail out. I am not understanding and not really helping.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with this question is that the probabilistic nature of the data is unclear. What sort of sample is it and how do we expect variations to occur due to sampling?

In an extreme case the sample is entirely the same as a the population and there is no probability occuring. For instance, if someone has the hypothesis that a vase filled with blue and red marbles has equal numbers of marbles of both colours then one can count *all* marbles and colours in the vase and decide with certainty whether the hypothesis is true or not.

Probability is necessary when we would only sample a fraction of the population or when in some other way our sample is not an exact representation of the numbers that we wish to estimate/infer. In order to make inference and estimate the error of estimates or in order to do hypothesis tests, it is important to know *how* the observations are susceptible to variation.

In the case of counts we might assume a Poisson, binomial or hypergeometric distribution for the distribution of the observations/measurements/sample, which have a known error/variance (or at least the relationship between the mean and variance is known) and we end up with the Chi-distribution (and Chi test) as an approximation.

In your case you need to find some way to express the error/variation of your measurements in relationship to the parameter/model that you wish to estimate/test. (Or maybe there is no error/variation at all?).